# Nilpotent matrix sets

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

Let's call a set of matrices $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, \ldots, A_k\}$ nilpotent if there is some $T$ such that the product of *every* $T$ matrices from $\mathcal{A}$ equals zero.

Then we have the following theorem: A set of $n \times n$ matrices $\mathcal{A}$ is nilpotent if and only if the product of every $n$ matrices from this set equals zero.

Is there a simple/natural proof of this? This statement is Proposition 2.1 [here](https://perso.uclouvain.be/raphael.jungers/sites/default/files/kcfinder/files/book.pdf). I can't follow the proof in that document, and in any case it is an induction on dimension, whereas it feels like this statement might have a better/conceptual argument.

Comment: Note: the proposition mentioned is on page 31 (47th page in the pdf)

Comment: Time for a MathOverflow repost?